# VBA excel table - How to sort based on ColorIndex

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am importing data from sharepoint as an excel table. After importing the data, I highlight some of the rows based on specific criteria.
I try to sort the excel table based on colorIndex using vba code, but I am not successful because the table name keeps changing each time the data is imported from sharepoint.
Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the actual code you have written. Then we can help more. As far as *I am not successful because the table name keeps changing each time the data is imported* is concerned, it's very possible to assign the table to a variable that you can assign (and thus not have to use the `name` all the time). I would even suggest changing the title of your question because the problem you have is the changing table name, not sorting by ColorIndex.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue with this code.

```
Sub SortTable()
Dim lo As Excel.ListObject

With ActiveSheet
     .ListObjects(1).Name = "MyTableName"
End With

Set lo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Alpha").ListObjects("MyTableName")
With lo
     .Sort.SortFields.Clear
     .Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("MyTableName[LastName]"), _
     xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.ColorIndex = 4
With .Sort
     .Header = xlYes
     .MatchCase = False
     .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
     .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    End With
End With

End Sub
```